# Howto distinguish Application Quit from System Shutdown

Tags: java, macos, swing

- Java on Mac OS X

In a Swing GUI app I want to distinguish Application Quit from System Shutdown.

On Application Quit I want to show a confirmation dialog, but when the user chooses System Shutdown I simply want to quit the app since there was already a confirmation dialog from the system.

This might be of interest on other platforms too.

Dirk

Answer (score 3):

For application quit, add a listener and use [windowClosed](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)) event on the main window.

For system quit, you can use [addShutdownHook](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)).

Answer (score 3):

The [`OSXAdapter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application shows how to (transparently) handle certain Apple events like quitting via ⌘-Q or from the dock menu.

Comment: why is MAC OX so different, hmmm that's really alchemy run basics ... (means including your last posts about MAC OX)

Comment: @mKorbel: Accommodating Mac quirks can also be a marketing edge. I'm often amazed at how well Swing abstracts popular GUIs, although there's nothing like cross-platform testing to exposes a misused layout manager! :-)

Comment: well, because lots of times Steve J told that they (Apple) don't want to Java platforms on their cell/ipac/laptop's, maybe about C++, maybe we must learnt again C# and Assembler :-), same good news as :-) over my head is now a lunar eclipse (CET 9:20pm), errrghtt but sky full of storm clouds, that's really amazing, heavens next period is on 2016

Answer (score 1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

It's probably better in this case to stay with the standard behaviour.  If you look at other Mac apps, like Terminal, TextEdit, etc., they all provide their own dialogs in all cases, whether on app quit, user logout, or system shutdown.  Going with what users are used to is always the best choice!