# Override Quit Task on Mac && PC (CMD+Q / ALT+F4)

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, jframe

I'm having an issue with my application regarding quitting. 
What I want is for it to perform a task of my choosing before it quits, no matter how it is exited. (aside from the force quit in Task Manager and or Activity Monitor of course) I've successfully managed to have my app perform this task when the "X" button is pressed. 
Code for that:

```
    WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){

            int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog
            (null, "Are You Sure You Want to Close Application?", 
            "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

            if (confirm == 0){
                ProcessCommand pc = new ProcessCommand();

                if(sRunning){
                    pc.sendText("stop");
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    };

    frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
```

That works wonderfully until I press Cmd+Q(Apple) or Alt+F4 (Windows). 
How would I go about handling those two events in a similar manner?

Comment: Windows 7, Alt+F4 triggers a `windowClosing` for me...

Comment: Look at [`Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6209853/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson You do not want to put the code he is currently showing (the confirm dialog) in a shut down hook

Comment: [maybe???](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6121990/714968)

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2320770/230513).